# Calling STA component from ASP.NET Core code (async/non-async)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

I have an ASP.NET Core 5.0 application where I am integrating a WPF component. The component renders a chart. The issue is that WPF requires STA (Single Thread Apartment). The thread pool used by ASP.NET is MTA. That leads to the exception:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

I know there are a lot of workarounds available like the following:

```
    public static Task<T> RunThreadWithSTA<T>(Func<T> f)
    {
        var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                completionSource.SetResult(f());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                completionSource.SetException(e);
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        return completionSource.Task;
    }
```

It works fine (for sync code, but not async code). However this takes away threads from ASP.NET as is considered **bad practice**.

Other methods (from 10 years ago) have also been suggested, like a custom STA Thread Pool, see [Can the WPF API be safely used in a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363397/can-the-wpf-api-be-safely-used-in-a-wcf-service/2367409#2367409) but I am not very inclined towarding changing the thread-pool.

So as far as I can see there is no suggested method of handling this.

Comment: *However this takes away threads from ASP.NET as is considered bad practice.* ... well, it is not worse practie than using WPF in  ASP.NET server code ... so here is the problem ... suggestion: do not use WPF at all find library for generating charts without dependency to WPF/ dedicated for ASP.NET Core

Comment: I am not sure that the `RunThreadWithSTA` takes away threads from ASP.NET. It creates a dedicated STA thread. It doesn't borrow threads from the `ThreadPool` that serves is a pool of workers for ASP.NET requests. I would be more concerned about how much CPU-hungry is this WPF integration, and I would ask how many STA threads you expect to have running concurrently at maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, you are right RunThreadWithSTA does not take them out of the ThreadPool, but it still takes them from the same process. I guess it's not really an issue as this is not a performance critical application. @Selvin, I am kind of stuck with it, I am using SciChart...